# How much should I worry about not being in the right job field?

Tags: career-development, software-development

I've been doing freelance Web Design for a short while now (I've only had two clients), and I had a concern about the future of my career.

Although I don't mind doing this type of work, my career goal is to do more Software Engineering work as opposed to designing websites for people.

The main reason I am doing web design is because of the demand for it (everybody wants a website these days), but how important is it for the rest of my career to make an effort to start doing more software engineering work  *now*?

Comment: In what stage of your software career are you? Beginning, middle, advanced?

Comment: @DarkCygnus beginning

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> how important is it for the rest of my career to make an effort to
>   start doing more software engeneering work now?

As they say, *there's no time like the present*.

If you really want to be a Software Engineer, then be one. If you want to be a freelancer doing whatever a client or two happens to want done at the moment, then do that instead (that approach can be lucrative too). Either way make a choice and work on it mindfully.

If you are serious about a career, whatever your choice in career is, then make every step count. Before taking on a freelance gig ask yourself "Is this going to take me further in my career?" If it will, then take the gig. If not, then pass on it and find a gig that will move you toward your real goal.

If you want to be a Software Engineer, then make an effort.

Answer (score 0):

> but how important is it for the rest of my career to make an effort to start doing more software engeneering work now?

If you want to stop doing purely web development then it is of **utmost importance to start trying to switch to your work of interest as early as possible.**

If you have a goal or career path in mind not pursuing it is a bad idea. I suggest that you try to change to Software Engineering as soon as you can, or try to land an offer where your role is the one you seek.